# Changing the cell color to specific defined color

Tags: java, excel

I want to change the color of the cell to a color, that I define with `java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
I used the code:

```
Color sColor = new Color(200, 0, 0);
XSSFColor userColor = new XSSFColor(sColor);
try
{
    CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
    Font font = wb.createFont();
    font.setColor(userColor.getIndexed());
    style.setFont(font);
    cell.setCellStyle(style);
}
catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException ex) 
{
    //Handle NumberFormat and NullPointer exceptions here    
}
```

the color always remains black.

And the output of `System.out.print(userColor);` is: >(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor@2e1b928).
Actually, it changes depending on the value that I type in `new Color (200,0,0);`

but the output of `System.out.print(userColor.getIndexed());` is always: (0).

any tips?

Comment: IIRC, you need to prefix teh RGB values with "RGB". ex.: `rgb(255, 255, 255)` Someone smarter than me can probably confirm this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you instantiate Font as **XSSFFont**, you can use the method

```
XSSFFont.setColor(XSSFColor) // Takes a color object, not a short!
```

See the documentation here: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFont.html#setColor-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor-

So try this (it worked for me in a quick test):

```
Color sColor = new Color(200, 0, 0);
XSSFColor userColor = new XSSFColor(sColor);

CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
XSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
font.setColor(userColor);
style.setFont(font);
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Comment: I am totally convinced.
But although I import the library, I still have error on XSSFFont font = wb.createFont();.
do you have any suggestion.
@RaceYouAnytime

Comment: Compiler suggest .add cast to XSSFFont
                        or . change type to Font

Comment: @EzzEddinOthman what implementation of Workbook are you using?

Comment: this question is kind of too old, but if you are still there,>>> is there any way to do the same thing with Background??